# How to show complete video inside (wix) iframe?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to display a video that is inside a `wix iframe` in my page.

However, the video is display by the half and users need to scroll to see the other half. I need it to display completly.

[image]

**Codepen:**

https://codepen.io/ogonzales/pen/XWmqJOZ

**UPDATE 1:**

Removing all extra tags, and keeping only:

```
<iframe width="100%" height="100%" name="htmlComp-iframe" src="https://www-ministerioselimlosangeles-net.filesusr.com/html/c6c2ba_7e10543906cc3e0dfef547110eb63f30.html"></iframe>
```

Shows all the video, but the heigh goes to bottom.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are using bootstrap-4, you may use the responsive iframe class. Add `embed-responsive` and `embed-responsive-16by9` class to `<div id="comp-iq9y0o3iiFrameHolder">` Then, add `embed-responsive-item` class and set 'no' to `scrolling` in iframe tag.

Other responsive iframe ratios in Bootstrap:

- .embed-responsive-21by9
- .embed-responsive-4by3
- .embed-responsive-1by1

```
<div id="comp-iq9y0o3iiFrameHolder" class="htco1iFrameHolder embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9">
    <iframe class="embed-responsive-item" name="htmlComp-iframe" scrolling="no" src="https://www-ministerioselimlosangeles-net.filesusr.com/html/c6c2ba_7e10543906cc3e0dfef547110eb63f30.html">
    </iframe>
</div>
```

Comment: Ty. Would you share some documentation on this? totally ignored this classes.

Comment: I refer to https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/embed/